# Converting ENVI grid to Esri shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, envi

I have build geographic coordinates grid for raster in ENVI. It can be saved in  grd format only, but I need shp (shapefile) format for opening it in ArcGIS Desktop or MapInfo.

Does anyone know how to convert it?

Comment: What version are you using ENVI ? I've use it in the past but since I no longer use it...

Comment: https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/RasterToVector.html

Comment: ENVI version is 5.1,

Comment: I suggest you to work with it in ENVI first and then bring it in ArcGIS. This way you don't face problems. If I remember right, It did happen to me  in the past.  I gave you the link above.

Answer (score 2):

ENVI grids are a simple [flat-binary raster file](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/ENVIImageFiles.html)  with an accompanying [ASCII header file](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/enviheaderfiles.html)

You don't need to convert an ENVI grid to a shapefile to open in ArcMap, it can open it as is.  I don't use MapInfo so can't comment on that software.

Regardless, even if ArcMap and MapInfo could not read ENVI grids, I would not convert from a raster to a vector format.  I would convert to a GeoTIFF which is a almost universally supported raster format.

.

Comment: I tried the way you told, but it does not works. But thanks

Comment: Yes it works. If you are having trouble, edit your question and add more details, in particular what exactly happens when you try to add a grid to ArcGIS, include the header of the grid as plain text formatted using the `{}` button. Saying"it doesn't work" is not helpful.